# IE8 crashes on pagination and refresh the application

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, pagination

My application got crash on IE8 on pagination. Its works fine for IE9 and for other browsers also.

Comment: This is FAR TOO LITTLE information. Please add a LOT more - you have been a member for a year and do not know this?

Comment: Like on pagination when we click on > to show next contents , it crashes. Actually i also don't know why it is happening?

Comment: Please update your question with a) what pagination your use. b) code example - for example a jsfiddle.net